# Why does xsd.exe generate a schema that makes all attributes required?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd-validation

In my code I have the following class to deserialize XML:

```
public abstract class AssetBase
{
    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public float RelativeX { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public float RelativeY { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public float RelativeZ { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public float ScaleX { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public float ScaleY { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `xsd.exe` to define a schema for this, the schema sets it up so these properties are required for validation.

How can I set this class up so that these can be left empty by the user, as not all of these are mandatory?

---

**Edit**:
I just looked at the xsd it generated and saw:

```
  <xs:complexType name="AssetBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="RelativeX" type="xs:float" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="RelativeY" type="xs:float" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="RelativeZ" type="xs:float" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="ScaleX" type="xs:float" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="ScaleY" type="xs:float" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="Visible" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
```

I'm confused as to why Name isn't set to be required but the rest are...

Comment: Is it because a `string` is nullable and the other types (`float` and `bool`) are not? Just guessing.

Comment: That's a good thought.  Unfortunately it appears like xsd.exe cannot deal with `float?` and `bool?` attributes, as it fails on them.  Using `[XmlElement]` instead does generate an xsd but it requires a full element node listed as nil and doesn't let you not specify it :-/

Comment: Have you tried adding `[XmlRoot(IsNullable=true)]` to `AssetBase` to allow the nullable types to serialize correctly using Attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered yourself `Nullable<T>` doesn't just work with `[XmlAttribute]` as it's a complex type. You'll have to use the 'magic' property *Specified to deal with this.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public float? RelativeX
{
    get { return this.RelativeX; }
    set { this.RelativeX = value; }
}

[XmlAttribute("RelativeX")]
public float RelativeXValue
{
    get { return this.RelativeX.Value; }
    set { this.RelativeX = value; }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public bool RelativeXValueSpecified
{
    get { return this.RelativeX.HasValue; }
}
```

Your other options are:

- Use strings for all of your attributes and have corresponding properties of the right type
- Implement `IXmlSerializable`

Comment: How will that help XSD generation though?  The XMLAttribute value is still a non-nullable type, which will cause xsd.exe to make the xsd generate with required

Comment: The XmlSerializer should see the Specified property and infer that it's optional. If RelativeXValueSpecified is false the attribute will be left out entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I found this explanation :

> Use Attribute: Generating an XML Schema document from classes
>
> In either of the following two cases, Xsd.exe does not specify the use attribute, reverting to the default value optional:
>
> • An extra public bool field that follows the Specified naming convention is present.
>
> • A default value is assigned to the member via an attribute of type System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute.
>
> If neither of these conditions is met, Xsd.exe produces a value of required for the use attribute.

From [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958062/how-to-generate-xml-schema-from-c-sharp-type-with-xsd-exe-such-that-xmlattribut?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I used the default value way and it works fine :)

Enjoy !!!