# How to generate XML Schema from C# type with XSD.exe such that [XmlAttribute] property is mapped to required XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

Put it simply, when I use XSD.exe (that comes with Visual Studio 2012) to generate XML schema file from this class:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I get this as the result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Person" nillable="true" type="Person" />
  <xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="Age" type="xs:int" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Notice that *Age* attribute is specified as required (it has **use="required"**) in generated schema while attribute *Name* is not.

I use XSD.exe like this:

```
xsd.exe Sample.exe /type:Person
```

Where Sample.exe is .NET assembly where Person class is defined.

I would like to somehow specify in my class which XmlAttribute properties are required and which are not so that XSD.exe can automatically generate schema from that. Is this possible?

Comment: FWIW, XSD.EXE is not a great tool.  Microsoft stopped working on it years ago, and I still find the occasional bug in it.

Comment: Could you recommend an alternative tool? I'd like to automatically generate XSD files (in project post-build event) whenever I change my XML-serializable class in C# code.

Comment: [XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is pretty good.  If you want a free tool, you can try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133570/XmlToXsd-A-Better-Schema-Generator

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I need to generate XSD file from C# code (or more generally, from .NET type/class). Is this possible with specified tools?

Comment: That's why I recommended the CodeProject article.

Comment: I've just checked that, article is about generating XSD from XML but not from C# class. That doesn't solve my problem but thanks for the effort, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a bug in XSD (it is not clear if you tried what it is described in the XSD.exe documentation, specifically the [attribute element binding support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6sktzs3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - right now I can't test it), the answer is yes, you can.

In your case, the different behaviour between Name and Age is simply due to the fact that a String field is nullable, whereas the int one is not (somehow I don't believe an `int?` will make a difference in your case, still you can try it...) Attributes are not nillable (from an XSD perspective), therefore the use of optional.

> Use Attribute: Generating an XML Schema document from classes
>
> In either of the following two cases, Xsd.exe does not specify the use
> attribute, reverting to the default value optional:
>
> • An extra public bool field that follows the Specified naming convention is present.
>
> • A default value is assigned to the member via an attribute of type
> System.Component.DefaultValueAttribute.
>
> If neither of these conditions is met, Xsd.exe produces a value of required for the use attribute.

Comment: What I actually need more is to make "Name" (a string property in above class) to be required attribute of an element in XML file. You focused on integer in your answer and making it optional which is fine. However, I am not sure how to make string property of a class mapped to XSD file to have use="required" in schema generated by xsd.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: If you go through the provided link, you may notice how the XmlAttributeAttribute works for reference types (string being one of them). The conclusion is that for reference types, there is no way to enforce the use=required (at least that I can infer or been made aware of). In other words, there is no way to roundtrip correctly between an XSD and code generated by XSD.exe for reference types (XSD to code, code to XSD).